# C# Program can only run once + BringToFront if started a 2nd time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want my program to be startable only once (it doesn't matter if it can be started on other user-accounts).

If its already started and the .exe is opened again it should bring the main-window of the first instance to the front.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog series might be helpful](http://dzimchuk.net/blog/post/Single-instance-of-a-WPF-app-e28093-part-1-%28introduction%29.aspx) (see other options subsequent parts linked at bottom). I personally like the method described in [Part 4](http://dzimchuk.net/blog/post/Single-instance-of-a-WPF-app-e28093-part-4-%28WindowsFormsApplicationBase%29.aspx) since in the Windows Forms world I've had good success using the `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into using the Mutex object. Basically when your program runs check to see if a Mutex exists the "your unique name", if it does - close application (do this check before loading all resources), otherwise create a Mutex with the unique name and load up your application as planned.